# System.Collections.Generic.List`1

Tags: c#, list, объекты

товарищи знатоки! Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Программа должна создавать метод для фильтрации списка по заданным параметрам. В качестве параметров должны задаваться сам список, свойство для фильтрации(Name или Surname) и текстовое значение.

**Вопросы:**

1. Изначально была ошибка CS0103(на Объект в вызове Filtr()), получилось избавиться от неё, теперь проект запускается, но в консоли выдаёт

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[arrayfiltr.Object]

Видел статью с таким же вопросом на англ стаке, но не понял, как это применить у себя в коде, а на ру не нашёл ничего, что помогло б.

2. Обязательно ли задавать Name или Surname как параметр, нельзя задать просто текстовое значение, как прописано у меня в коде?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace arrayfiltr
{
    class Object
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        public static List<Object> Objects = new List<Object>
        {
            new Object { Name="Ivan", Surname="Ivanov"},
            new Object { Name="Petr", Surname="Petrov"},
            new Object { Name="Vasiliy", Surname="Vasiliev"}
         };
     }

    class Program : Object
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Filtr(Objects,"Ivan");
        }

        static void Filtr(List<Object> Objects, string Name)
        {
            List<Object> newObjects = new List<Object> { };

            var selectedObject = from Object in Objects
                                 where Object.Name == Name
                                 select Object;

            foreach (Object Object in selectedObject)
                newObjects.Add(Object);
            Console.WriteLine(newObjects);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что вы хотите? Вывести список в консоль?

Comment: вывести отфильтрованный список в консоль с помощью созданного метода

Comment: Мне кажется, вы изобретаете велосипед, делая двойную работу и лишний метод, ибо что трудного в том, чтоб в нужном месте прописать `var result = objects.Where(x=>x is {Name: "Вася"});` и сразу получить то, что вам надо? Зачем вот сейчас вам метод, который составляет коллекцию, потом заполняет другую, а затем все это отдает наружу для дальнейшей работы, не лишнее?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, `x is {Name: "Вася"}` это то же самое что и `x.Name == "Вася"`?

Comment: @Grundy Скорей `x != null && x.Name == "Вася"`, ибо `x is {}`, проверка на то, что объект не null.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, то есть `x?.Name == "Вася"`? :-)

Comment: @Grundy Да, можно и так) Весьма удобная фича, которая позволяет проверить без труда разные значения, включая вложенные, например: `x is {Name: "Вася", Age: 13, City: { Code: "RU" } }`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, элвис выглядит удобнее :)

Comment: @Grundy Тут уже кому как, лично мне не особо нравиться писать конструкции по типу `x?.Name == "Вася" && x?.Age == 13 && x?.City?.Code == "RU"`, ибо постоянное обращение к объекту, дублирование этих переменных, ну не знаю... С одной проверкой, может да, но когда их несколько, это иногда превращается в кашу). Вон [набросал](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WqDnRK), для меня первый вариант предпочтительней))

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, если по строкам отформатировать: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0T2C10 лучше смотреть :)

Comment: @Grundy Как не крути, но это всеравно портянка кода с кучей ненужных повторений. К тому же, новый синтаксис позволяет ведь не только это делать, там есть всякие `is not` `or` `and`, всякие `_` и тому подобные фишки. Вообще весь этот синтаксис лучше раскрывается в новом `switch`, который в добавок к этому еще и в диапазоны умеет. Также не забываем, что таким синтаксисом можно кастовать сразу к нужному типу (`x is Person {Name: "Вася"}`). В общем, фича весьма удобная)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newObjects.ForEach(obj => Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", obj.Name, obj.Surname))
```

Или же перегрузите метод `ToString()`:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0} {1}", Name, Surname);
}

...

newObjects.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

А еще лучше вот так:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumeration, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach(T item in enumeration)
    {
        action(item);
    }
}

...


var selectedObjects = from Object in Objects
                     where Object.Name == Name
                     select Object;

selectedObject.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```